# Merging dataframes in R on a pre-sorted column?

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I usually work with big dataframes that are pretty well sorted (or can be easily sorted).

Given two dataframes, both sorted by 'user'

```
some.data <user> <data_1> <data_2> 
user <user> <user_attr_1> <user_attr_2>
```

And I run `m = merge(some.data,user)`, I receive the result as:

```
m = <user> <data_1> <data_2> <user_attr_1> <user_attr_2>
```

And this is fine so.

But `merge` doesn't take advantage of these dataframes being sorted on the common column making the merge pretty CPU/memory heavy. However, this merge could be done in O(n)

I am wondering if there is a way in R to conduct an efficient merge on sorted datasets?

Comment: Unless I can come up with anything more substantive to add, Nick's answer is what I'd recommend.  The only other thing is that it's good to clear out any unused or unnecessary variables when doing merges: you end up having to move around that much more data when creating the new data frame.  I often create temporary variables in a data frame (or data table) and then nuke them (e.g. `myDT$tmpVar = NULL`) before merging or sorting the objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have any experience with it, but as far as I know, this is one of the issues that package `data.table`was designed to improve.

For most practical purposes, `data.table`=`data.frame` + `index`. As a consequence, when used right, this improves performance of quite a few large operations.

There is a danger that turning your `data.frame` into a `data.table` (i.e. adding the index) could take some time (although I expect this to be well optimized), but once you've got it up, functions like merge can easily use the index for better performance.

Comment: This is a good answer. To clarify: adding the index doesn't really occur - data.table uses the data itself to create keys (though limited to integers or numerics that are integers, AFAIK).  In order to do that, it sorts the data by the specified key *variables*.  If the data is already mostly sorted by these keys, then the complete sort is pretty fast.  It's not necessary, however, to specify keys - one can still use `merge`.

Comment: (Continued) For these and other reasons, all related to speed, I've recently switched a lot of data frames to data tables, and haven't regretted it - it's fast and I benchmarked it against 10 or so alternatives.  Without it, I would be writing a lot of code in C or C++ to do just a fraction of what I could do with it.  (A look at a bunch of questions I've posted will make that learning process rather clear. ;-))

Answer (score 0):

If your set of common keys/indexes is totally overlapping, that is...

`` Reduce(`&`, user$user.id %in% some.data$user.id) ``

...returns TRUE and they are, as you said, sorted,**and there are no key duplicates** then your merging problem is reduced to adding columns to a data.frame. Something in the lines along...

```
library(log4r)

t1 <- system.time(z <- merge(user, some.data, by='user.id'))

info(my.logger, paste('Elapsed time with merge():', t1['elapsed']))

t2 <- Sys.time()

r <- data.frame(user.id=user$user.id, V1.x=user$V1, V2.x=user$V2)

r[,names(some.data)] <- some.data[,names(some.data)

t3 <- Sys.time()

info(my.logger, paste('Elapsed time without:', t3-t2))
```

If the assumptions above do not hold, then it gets slightly messier set union of both key sets, translation function, NA padding) but the merging and overlapping assumption alone gets you a long way ahead.

Notice also that the timing of the seconds approach is biased since it's calling twice Sys.time() unlike the merge() timing which calls system.time() and only once.
(Excuse my lame usage of S.O. mark-up)